# How to Remote Debug ASP.NET Core on an Azure App Service from a Mac?

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, visual-studio-mac

I am developing an ASP.NET Core project that uses an Azure App Service. My development environment is **Visual Studio for Mac**. There are lots of documents like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure which explain how to do this from Windows. But I can't find anything for the Mac.

Comment: Attaching to a remote process is not currently supported via the .Net Core Debugger on `VS4M`

Answer (score 0):

You could look at capturing intellitrace logs and take them on your Mac.

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-intellitrace-stand-alone-collector

Or, the new snapshot debugger... https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/snapshot-debugger-for-azure/

Comment: IntelliTrace stand-alone collector does not seem to work with ASP.Net Core projects on the Mac. Are you sure that this can be done? The Snapshot Debugger sounds like it could fit the bill. I signed up for the private preview. I'll mark your answer as correct if it works.